# Scheme Programming Language:Installation on Windows 10 and How to run?

Tags: scheme

**Scheme Programming Language:Installation  on Windows 10 and How to run?**

Hello all. I am new on Scheme language. I am trying too run some sample scheme program on Windows 10 but I am not finding any tool to run. If somebody can give me some idea how to run and install any tool for scheme on Windows 10.

Comment: There are many terminal based ones, but if you want to develop i suggest you use [DrRacket](http://racket-lang.org/). It supports R5RS, R6RS, R7RS and a family of racket languages that are mostly compatible with Scheme.

Comment: If you first install the Windows package manager Chocolatey, you’ll find that lots of Scheme implementations can be installed automatically, for instance `choco install chicken`.